# Displaying big doubles in C

Tags: c, printing, double

I've got a problem with diplaying big doubles.

Here's a code I've prepared:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#define M_PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944
int main()
{
    printf("%.70f\n",M_PI);
    return 0;
}
```

It displays:

```
3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615905761718750000000000000000000000
```

But once I change M_PI for DBL_MAX everything is shown correctly.
What's worse is that when dot in M_PI definition is removed (leaving a really big number) the result is 0.

What do I do wrong? How can I display some huge numbers?

Comment: Removing the dot changes it to an integer. Try moving the dot to the end instead.

Comment: After moving it, 0 is no longer displayed but the number has chagned value after 16 digit, just like M_PI in my question.

Comment: `double` has effectively 53 bits of significand, equivalent to about 15.9 decimal digits, so rounding error after the 16th significant digit should be expected, and is nothing to do with printing.

Answer (score 0):

In IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point, the most common implementation of `double`, 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875 is the closest representable number to 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944, and so is what should be printed. In most cases, rounding error on conversion to double will appear after about 16 decimal digits.

`DBL_MAX`, by its definition, has to be exactly representable as a double, so there is no rounding error on its conversion from decimal string to double.